# Creating a level of numbers for a pass scoring system

Tags: php, json

I have a set of values from a json_decode and they look like this the number being the row 'pass_levels' and the letter being the row 'pass_level_name'.

```
90 -> A, 80 -> B, 70 -> C
```

I have a score that if it is above or below a certain number I want it to show the letter. So if I score 85 it shows a B. The problem I have with the code below is that if the score is above any of the numbers it shows a C regardless.

I know I could do if > 90 echo A but the variables are not set and the amount of variables could change. So it could change and the variables might be:

```
A -> 95, B -> 90, C -> 80, D -> 70, E -> 60, F -> 50.
```

In all circumstances anything scored below the lowest number would be a fail.

```
$score = $row['score'];


$levels = json_decode($row['pass_levels']);
$levels_name = json_decode($row['pass_level_name']);

foreach(array_combine($levels, $levels_name) as $level => $level_name){                 
}

if($score >= $level){ echo $score.'% '.$level_name; } else { echo "Fail"; }
```

I hope I've explained this clearly enough for you to help me.

Thanks

Comment: what code you want to execute in foreach loop? and how this `array_combine($levels, $levels_name)` looks like can you show print_r() format of this combined array?

Comment: Yes as I said the foreach returns the array [90] => A [80] => B [70] => C

Comment: so in that I have to find all the levels that are available

Comment: can you give example value of $score and the value you want to get printed in your foreach loop

Comment: The foreach can be replaced by an simple [`array_flip`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php). And If I understand correct you want everything higher than the 'A' key to be 'A'. So find the highest key with `$mx = max(array_keys($arr));` and just compare `if($score > $mx) $levl='A';`

Comment: that only gives me the max, I need to be able to check against all the scores, someone might have a score of 85 and it should be a B

Comment: @Durga I have given examples of scores in the second paragraph. The foreach loop is my way of combining the two arrays together. I would say i need to get all of the values inside of the foreach of 'pass_levels' and then compare those values to the score to obtain which pass level I should print